# container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar

Tags: android

First of all, i know this question has been asked a lot, but nothing seem to be working for me.I have installed Eclipse ADT On MAC 10.9.5 from android.developer.com and have installed latest Android SDK tools, and all other platform and tools required for Android 5.0, android 4.4W and Android 4.4.2. I have also installed Android support library. But when i try to run the project with the default properties,

http://postimg.org/image/4lf8ayl99/

Minimum Required :  SDK-API8:Android 2.2(Froyo)
Target SDk-Android;   4.x(L Preview)
Compile With ;   API 21: Android 4.x( L Preview)

It always give me error, 
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/xxx/Documents/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar'
I went through all the solutions listed on web and on this website too, but nothing worked for me.
appcompat_v7 library gets generated, and then i click on add to build path for android-support-v7-appcompat.jar and android-support-v4.jar, and then from build path add the two libraries and untick android dependencies and add the library to my project from android library. From other posts i get to know that after clean and build appcompat_v7 library project , appcompat_v7.jar would be generated in bin directory, but it doesn't happen in my case.
Please help. I have spent too much time looking for the solution, but didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, I had to update the jdk to 1.8, The jdk installed by default by eclipse ADT form android.developer.com doesn't seem to be updated and Since API 21 requires jdk 1.7 or above thus i had to install it from JDK official website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html. Finally i got the support library appcompat_v7 working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried and after that message I got another from the res folder. Anyways what I did was switch work space and it worked fine . it should create those files for you as long as you downloaded the extras from android manager downloader.